# how to deduce new individuals with sparql query on eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, sparql, jena, inference

this program might use the inference technique for adding to the ontology other lion individuals deduced by inference but i don't know how to resolve all the errors returned. The java code is as follow:

```
package paletrasi;

import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.*;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.vocabulary.RDF;
import org.apache.jena.atlas.io.IndentedWriter;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.query.*;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.InfModel;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.Model;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.ModelFactory;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.Resource;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.reasoner.Reasoner;
import org.mindswap.pellet.jena.PelletReasonerFactory;
public class jungle2
{
public static final String NL = System.getProperty("line.separator") ;
public static void main( String[] args ) {
// create the simplest model there is
//
String jungle_file = "C:/Users/acer/workspace/paletrasi/src/paletrasi/junglejena.owl";
// create Pellet reasoner
Reasoner reasoner = PelletReasonerFactory.theInstance().create();
// create an empty model
Model emptyModel = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel( );
//create an inferencing model using Pellet reasoner
InfModel m = ModelFactory.createInfModel( reasoner, emptyModel );
//read the file
m.read( jungle_file );
//Model m = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel();
System.out.println( "We have loaded a model with no. statements = " + m.size() );
String jungle ="http://www.lirmm.fr/jungle#";
String prolog1 = "PREFIX jungle: <"+jungle+">" ;
String prolog2 = "PREFIX rdf: <"+RDF.getURI()+">" ;
//Query string.
String queryString = prolog1 + NL + prolog2 + NL +
"SELECT ?individu WHERE {?individu rdf:type jungle:Lion }" ;
Query query = QueryFactory.create(queryString) ;
//Print with line numbers
query.serialize(new IndentedWriter(System.out,true)) ;
System.out.println() ;
//Create a single execution of this query, apply to a model
//which is wrapped up as a Dataset
QueryExecution qexec = QueryExecutionFactory.create(query, m) ;
//Or QueryExecutionFactory.create(queryString, model) ;
System.out.println("Les Lions : ") ;
try {
//Assumption: it’s a SELECT query.
ResultSet rs = qexec.execSelect() ;
//The order of results is undefined.
for ( ; rs.hasNext() ; )
{
QuerySolution rb = rs.nextSolution() ;
//Get title - variable names do not include the ’?’
RDFNode y = rb.get("individu");
System.out.print("uri : "+y+"--- ");
Resource z = (Resource) rb.getResource("individu");
System.out.println("plus simplement "+z.getLocalName());
}
}
finally
{
//QueryExecution objects should be closed to free any system resources
    qexec.close() ;
    }
}}
```

the errors are:

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Users/acer/Desktop/apache-jena-2.11.1/apache-jena-2.11.1/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.6.4.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Users/acer/Downloads/Compressed/pellet-2.3.1/pellet-2.3.1/lib/jena/slf4j-log4j12-1.6.4.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.jena.riot.RiotException: <C:/Users/acer/workspace/paletrasi/src/paletrasi/junglejena.owl> Code: 11/LOWERCASE_PREFERRED in SCHEME: lowercase is preferred in this component
    at org.apache.jena.riot.system.IRIResolver.exceptions(IRIResolver.java:299)
    at org.apache.jena.riot.system.IRIResolver.access$000(IRIResolver.java:31)
    at org.apache.jena.riot.system.IRIResolver$IRIResolverNormal.resolve(IRIResolver.java:402)
    at org.apache.jena.riot.system.IRIResolver$IRIResolverSync.resolve(IRIResolver.java:437)
    at org.apache.jena.riot.system.IRIResolver.resolveIRI(IRIResolver.java:178)
    at org.apache.jena.riot.system.IRIResolver.resolveString(IRIResolver.java:169)
    at org.apache.jena.riot.RiotReader.createParser(RiotReader.java:128)
    at org.apache.jena.riot.RDFParserRegistry$ReaderRIOTFactoryImpl$1.read(RDFParserRegistry.java:141)
    at org.apache.jena.riot.RDFDataMgr.process(RDFDataMgr.java:859)
    at org.apache.jena.riot.RDFDataMgr.read(RDFDataMgr.java:255)
    at org.apache.jena.riot.RDFDataMgr.read(RDFDataMgr.java:241)
    at org.apache.jena.riot.adapters.RDFReaderRIOT_Web.read(RDFReaderRIOT_Web.java:96)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.impl.ModelCom.read(ModelCom.java:241)
    at paletrasi.jungle2.main(jungle2.java:32)
```

all help is apreciated :) thank you in advance
.

Answer (score 0):

`NotFoundException: C:/Users/acer/workspace/paletrasi/src/paletrasi/jungleJena.owl#`

as it says - not found.  (Why is there a # on the end?)

Comment: I've delated # but I get an exeption. Please check the edit to see it.

Comment: @user3347859 If the original error was filenotfound, then you shouldn't edit the question and change it.  This makes answers that were correct for the original question wrong for the current question.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this error
"Code: 11/LOWERCASE_PREFERRED in SCHEME: lowercase is preferred in this component"
 is to write in lowercase i.e."c:/" not "C:/".

Comment: really, shouldn't this be something more like `file://…`?